# Specify the format of application temp/backup files in kde

Tags: files, kde, backup, editors

Many text editors will create temporary or backup files with the format `<filename>~`.  Because of this, folders appear very cluttered with tons of files duplicated in this way ( `<original>` & `<original>~` many times over).

I'd like to specify that these kinds of auto-generated files have a prepended '.', so that they become hidden.

Any way to do this for the whole system?  Or are these file name definitions always application specific?

Comment: Honestly, I personally turn this off. It is a really really bad way of storing backups, neither safe or secure. It's way better to use `git` (or other questioning software) for your text files and do daily backups on top of that. I've found this in default `vim` settings, `set nobackup` in `.vimrc` solves it. I think `gedit` does that too and has the setting as well.

Comment: @CyprianGuerra For actual backing up of data you're right, these are terrible, but I think they're just for "oops" stuff.  It actually saved me a few days ago, accidentally deleted the wrong file but the ~<file> was there.  It has its uses.  I wrote a script that puts the . in front of those files to hide them, so they're not too annoying anymore.

Comment: It seems reasonable at glance but when you think about it... in a good workflow you should never `rm` a file that isn't backed up. And if this data is somehow important (assume passwords, for simplicity) and you just `rm original_file` without checking for `.original_file~`, then your data will be lying there for everyone with file read access to take. Also, if you've just deleted a file, it will probably be easy to restore (disk space shouldn't be overwritten).

Answer (score 0):

This is very application-specific.  The editor will have to be configured in such a way that it generates filenames with a prepended dot rather than a appended tilde. This may not be doable at all in some editors that only allows for specifying a backup *suffix*.

However, if your concern is about *seeing* the backup files, you can at least get `ls` to not list them.

With GNU `ls` (from the GNU coreutils), you may use the `-B` or `--ignore-backups` option.  This will explicitly not list files matching `*~`.  It is equivalent to `-I '*~'` or `--ignore='*~'`.

In your shell initialization file (`~/.bashrc` for `bash`), add either

```
alias ls='command ls -B'
```

or

```
function ls { command ls -B "$@"; }
```

Making the backup files not show up in file managers can probably be done as well, but how you accomplish this (if possible) depends on the file manager you use.